# PHP: replace text in the last brackets in string

Tags: php, regex

i thinking how can I replacing last item of form names like this:

```
content[1]
content[1][officeImage]
content[2][officeImage]
content[3][something][officeImage]
...
```

Depth of "array" can be infinity and I need replace last of him like this:

```
content[replaced]
content[1][replaced]
content[2][replaced]
content[3][something][replaced]
...
```

Is here someone who can write preg_replace() or etc?
Thanks

Edit:

I have this:

```
preg_replace('~\[.*!?\]~', '[replaced]', $parent);
```

But it return from "`content[1][officeImage]`" this "`content[replaced]`" :[

Comment: fetch that last item inside a variable and you can play according to your plan

Comment: post your attempts/..

Comment: Is it an array or a literal text?

Comment: @revo literal text

Comment: I have: preg_replace('~.*\K\[.*!?\]~s', '$1' . "[{$name}]", $parent) ... but i need append replacement before replacement. Is possible?

Comment: OK I have it:

`preg_match('~.*\K\[(.*)\]~s', $parent, $results);
str_replace($results[1], $results[1] . "_" . $name, $parent)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Try this:](https://regex101.com/r/yL3lH1/1)

```
preg_replace('~^.*\[\K[^]]+~m', 'replaced', $parent);
```

The `m` (multi-line) modifier is only necessary if `$parent` contains multiple lines needing to be replaced at once.

The big trick here is starting with `^.*\[\K`. This says match everything starting with the beginning of the line up to a `\[`. Since this is a "greedy" repetition it will keep going until the last instance (`.` doesn't match newlines without the `s` modifier). The `\K` throws away everything matched so we only are replacing what's inside the brackets.

Comment: I didn't know about `\K`, I'll have a look! Kudos to you :)

Comment: PCRE-only, but it can make more efficient queries less complicated in instances like this. You would be able to get away without `\K` here by replacing `~^(.*\[)[^]]+~m` with `\1[replaced`. Less elegant for sure.

Comment: Haha i found this right now:

preg_replace('~.*\K\[.*!?\]~s', '$1' . '[replaced]', $parent);

What is difference?

Comment: The difference is, it is something completely different that obviously doesn't work @landsman

Comment: @landsman, the difference is that the `\K` is resetting the match before the `[` and the regex extends to the final `]`. To summarize, mine doesn't match the `[]` and yours does (that's why your text replacement is `[replaced]` instead of `replaced`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$re = "/\\[([^]]*)\\][^]]*$/m"; 
$str = "content[1]\ncontent[1][officeImage]\ncontent[2][officeImage]\ncontent[3][something][officeImage]"; 
$subst = "[replacement]"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

See it [live PHP](https://ideone.com/tIckXH) or [live Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jN4tX7/1)

Comment: Definitely a workable approach, but the repetitive matching of `[]` sets adds more steps than necessary. (Just an FYI to the OP.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = 'content[3][something][officeImage]';
$replaced = 'somestring';
$result = preg_replace('/(.*\[)(.*?)]$/m','$1'.$replaced.']',$string);
```

Comment: Add the `m` modifier to make this expression work with multiple lines of input at once.